# ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] ONLY when running from .bat file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I am running Python 3.7 on an Anaconda distribution with Windows 10.

I have a script that runs without error in a Spyder ipython console. However, I need to run it from a .bat file.

I've replicated the error with the following Python code (just an import):

```
import pandas
```

And the following .bat:

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python "L:\path\baterrorimporttest.py"
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "L:\path\baterrorimporttest.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandas
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I have no issues running this script, importing pandas, using numpy, etc. in my Spyder console.

Any tips?

Comment: How are you running the .bat file? Clicking on it from explorer? From an Anaconda 3 command prompt?

Comment: @Rup it's running from a task scheduler, but I get the same result from clicking on it from explorer.

Comment: change current directory first, i.e. in your .bat file add "cd C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\" at first then the other command

Comment: @MahmoudElshahat just tried, didn't help unfortunately

Comment: Try calling Anaconda's scripts\activate.bat at the top of your file, i.e. something line `call c:\users\clg5\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat c:\users\clg5\Anaconda3`. This is the same line you'll see in the Anaconda3 Prompt shortcut if you look at that (albeit wrapped in a shell there, and without the `call`).

Comment: If you launch `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python` from the command line, can you successfully then `import pandas` from the resulting interpreter prompt?

Comment: @Rup I think this worked! I'll have to try it with my actual script but it fixed it for my test case- thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

to me worked with this piece of code:

```
call "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Anaconda"
"C:\Anaconda\python.exe" "C:\Users\...\ml001.py"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @Karl Knechtel:

Launch `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python` from the command line. You can then import pandas from the resulting interpreter prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your system path environment to include paths that look something like this:

```
C:\Users\name\Python.exe Folder\
C:\Users\name\Python.exe Folder\Library
C:\Users\name\Python.exe Folder\Library\bins
C:\Users\name\Python.exe Folder\Scripts
```

Not exactly sure about the mechanics behind this, but i had a similar problem and this helped.  I apologize for not remembering the link that helped me resolve this issue.

I'm a new user, and would appreciate if you mark this as closed (if it resolves your question).